# If GCD of x and y is G then GCD of x and x+y is also G. but how to prove it?

Tags: divisibility

If GCD of x and y is G then GCD of x and x+y is also G but how to prove it?

Comment: One strategy: The set of common divisors of $x$ and $y$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $x$ and $x+y$.

Comment: @divakar In case you didn't notice, if you look closely at evinda's answer you'll see that it is the same as I hinted, essentially showing $\,d\mid x,y\iff d\mid x,x\!+\!y.\ $ Conceptually this is the essence of the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$gcd(x,y)=G \Rightarrow G \mid x \text{ and } G \mid y$$

Then $G$ divides also any linear combination of $x$ and $y$, so it divides also their sum:

$G \mid x+y$

Therefore, a common divisor of $x$ and $x+y$ is $G$.

It is left to show that this divisor is the GREATEST common divisor.

We suppose that the greatest common divisor is $D>G$.

$D$ divides $x$ and $x+y$. So $D$ divides also any linear combination of $x$ and $x+y$, so it divides  also their difference: $D \mid x+y -x \Rightarrow D \mid y$

That means that $D$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $y$.

Since $G$ is the greatest divisor of $x$ and $y$, it must be $D \leq G$, a contradiction.

Therefore, there is no other common divisor of $x$ and $x+y$ that is greater than $G$. So $gcd(x,x+y)=G$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,d\mid x\,$ then $\,d\mid x\!+\!y\iff d\mid y.\,$ Thus $\,x,\,y\,$ and $\,x,\,x\!+\!y\,$ have the same set $\,S\,$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S).$

Comment: Hmm makes sense. thanks Bill and. Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\gcd(x, y) = d$ then $d|x$ and $d|y$, it follows that

$$x = dk_1, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
y=dk_2, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now, if $\gcd(x, x+y) = e$ then $e | x$ and $e|x+y$, it follows
$$e|dk_1+dk_2\\
e|d(k_1 + k_2)$$

Thus, $e|d$. Since $\gcd(x, x+y) = e \implies xl_1 + (x+y)l_2 = e$ and $d|x$ and $d|x+y$, $d|e$ therefore $d=e$.

Answer (score 0):

lat $u= (x,y)$ and $v=(x,x+y)$
$$
(a)
$$
$$
\exists m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.mx+ny = u
$$
so
$$
(m-n)x+n(x+y)=u
$$
implying
$$
v|u
$$
$$
(b)
$$
$$
\exists m',n' \in \mathbb{Z}.m'x+n'(x+y) =v
$$
so 
$$
(m'+n')x + n'y = v
$$
implying
$$
u|v
$$